# Windows: User environment variable cannot be displayed with echo

Tags: environment-variables, registry, windows-console

I am looking at a user environment variable created using Windows console command

```
reg add "hkcu\environment" /v SARMaster_Server_Name /d %smServer%
```

This variable name `SARMaster_Server_Name`  can be seen in the registry under `HKCU/Environment` with the correct value as well as through the advanced System settings of the Control Panel.

However, when I run

```
echo %SARMaster_Server_Name%
```

I get `%SARMaster_Server_Name%` instead of the actual value of this environment variable.  What did I miss?  All other environment variables such as TEMP can be echoed.

Comment: Is it listed when you type `SET`?

Comment: It is not listed when I type SET.

Comment: So the variable isn't being set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable is being set correctly using

```
reg add "hkcu\environment" /v SARMaster_Server_Name /d %smServer%
```

However, I need to restart to be able to access this variable.  A workaround, which does not help in my scenario is to open the Environment Variables editor from the Control Panel and click on OK after the variable has been added using "reg add". Somehow, this action registers the new variable which can now be accessed on a new CMD session.   Problem is being reported on XP so it may have been fixed on Windows 7 a

Comment: This question explains how that works:  http://serverfault.com/questions/8855/how-do-you-add-a-windows-environment-variable-without-rebooting